# Поштучное добавление элементов в динамический массив

Tags: c++, массивы, динамические-массивы

Как постепенно выделять по одной ячейке памяти для массива?

Comment: Такого лучше не делать, выделение памяти - дорогостоящая операция, лучше сразу запросить столько сколько нужно.

Comment: Массив каких данных?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы имеете ввиду обычные динамические массивы в C?
Если да, то примерно так:

```
int size = 0;
int * array = 0;
array = (int*)realloc(array, sizeof(int) * (++size)); //добавляем одну ячейку
array = (int*)realloc(array, sizeof(int) * (++size)); //еще одну
```

Но стоит отметить, что этот способ очень неэффективный, т.к. при каждой реалокации происходит копирование всего массива на новое место. Поэтому для создания массива размера N таким способом потребуется порядка N^2 операций, т.е. стоимость добавления одного элемента составит порядка N.  Намного эффективнее по мере надобности (в моменты, когда свобоного места в массиве не осталось) увеличивать массив на величину a * N, где a - некоторая константа, а N - текущий размер массива. В таком случае средняя стоимость добавления одного элемента будет константной. Именно такая стратегия реализована в стандартном классе vector. Поэтому я рекомендую воспользоваться им:

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.push_back(1);
v.push_back(20);
```

Answer (score 2):

Можете воспользоваться функциями realloc & malloc, но лучше для таких целей воспользоваться готовыми решениями из stl -> vector.

Answer (score -1):

Используя realloc:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *from = NULL;
    int amount = 1;

    while (true) {
        char *to = (char *)realloc(from, sizeof(char) * amount);

        if (!to)
            from = to;
        else
            break;
        amount++;
    }

    if (!from)
        free(from);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Мне только непонятна строчка 

if (!from) free(from);

Это получается, что  память должна освобождаться, если указатель указывает никуда?

Comment: Я тоже не очень понял. Если from == NULL, вы вызываете free(from)?

Comment: Логика "получлось-не получилось" везде реализована с точностью "до наоборот". `if (!to)`, `if (!from)`? Это уже не говоря о том, что проверять указатель перед `free` никакого смысла нет.